# create widget for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

this is my plugin code. the file is in plugin folder. here i am saving some data:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Losninger
Plugin URL: http://yyy.no
Description: Show losninger
Version: 1.0
Author: xxx - zzz zzz
Author URI: http://asd.com
Contributors: 
*/

/*
 * Register losninger
 *
 */
class losninger extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct(){
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'losninger',
            'description' => 'show losninger'
        );

        $this->WP_Widget(
            'losninger',
            'Losninger',
            $widget_ops
        );

add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'losninger_setup_post_types' ) );
add_action('widgets_init',create_function('','return register_widget("losninger");'));
add_action('init', 'losninger_setup_post_types');

wp_enqueue_style( 'losninger-Styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'losninger.css', array(), '0.1', 'screen' );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) { // widget sidebar output
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        echo $before_widget; // pre-widget code from theme

        $this->getLosninger();

        echo $after_widget; // post-widget code from theme
    }

    public function losninger_setup_post_types() {

        $losninger_labels =  apply_filters( 'losninger_labels', array(
            'name'                => 'Losninger',
            'singular_name'       => 'Losninger',
            'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'losninger'),
            'add_new_item'        => __('Add New losninger', 'losninger'),
            'edit_item'           => __('Edit losninger', 'losninger'),
            'new_item'            => __('New losninger', 'losninger'),
            'all_items'           => __('All losninger', 'losninger'),
            'view_item'           => __('View losninger', 'losninger'),
            'search_items'        => __('Search losninger', 'losninger'),
            'not_found'           => __('No losninger found', 'losninger'),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No losninger found in Trash', 'losninger'),
            'parent_item_colon'   => '',
            'menu_name'           => __('Losninger', 'losninger'),
            'exclude_from_search' => true
        ));


        $losninger_args = array(
            'labels' => $losninger_labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => apply_filters('losninger_supports', array( 'title', 'editor' ) ),
        );
        register_post_type( 'losninger', apply_filters( 'losninger_post_type_args', $losninger_args ) );

    }

    function getLosninger(){
        ob_start();

        // Create the Query
        $post_type = 'losninger';
        $orderby = 'menu_order';
        $order = 'ASC';
        $posts_per_page = 50;
        $query = new WP_Query( array ( 
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'orderby'        => $orderby, 
            'order'          => $order,
            'no_found_rows'  => 1
            ) 
        );
        //Get post type count
        $post_count = $query->post_count;
        $i = 1;
        // Displays FAQ info
        if( $post_count > 0) :
        // Loop
            echo '<section id="losningerSection"><div class="losningerSectionInner">';
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            ?>

                <div class="losninger">
                    <h3 class="losninger_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p id="losninger_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php
            $i++;
            endwhile;
            echo '</div></section>';
        endif;
        // Reset query to prevent conflicts
        wp_reset_query();
    }


}
```

How can I get this plugin as a widget? I want to show this widget in a page which will show the data (which i saved in plugin in admin).

NOTE: for some reason, i am not getting the admin part(left menu) for this plugin. i am sure i am doing something wrong here. can anyone help me out about this?

Answer (score 0):

In your function getLosninger, you start an output buffer ( ob_start() ), but you don't do anything with it.

You might be safe removing that line of code, or at least capturing the contents of the output buffer and flushing it.